# What do you need to do to get all of the League Card stars?

Tags: pokemon-sword-shield

In the Pokémon series starting with Ruby and Sapphire, you get [stars](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Trainer_Card_level) placed on your Trainer Card for reaching certain milestones in the game, such as Pokédex completion and entering the Hall of Fame. For the past few generations they have been denoted by background colors and, in (Ultra) Sun and Moon, stamps, but stars return in Sword and Shield. Unlike past games, though, they seem to be more easily obtained. *Like* the past games, of course, it's not exactly clear what the criteria is to get each star. I have all of the stars so far, but I'm curious as to what the exact criteria is to get them.

What milestones must be reached to get each of the stars on your League Card in Pokémon Sword and Shield?

Comment: According to different Reddit users, you shoud have 2 with the first 4 badges, you get 2 more with the remaining, making a total of 4. And defeating the Champions gives you the 5th. But I feel it's not related only to badges.

Answer (score 4):

You get 5 stars for beating the main game, then you get a 6th star for beating Isle of Armor, and you get your 7th star for beating the Galarian Star Tournament.

Comment: This is correct, but at which points do you get the first five stars? They're not obtained all at once by beating Leon; they are obtained at various points throughout the main story.

Comment: I have a problem with both previous answers submitted because I've cleared the full main story and post plot, in addition to clearing the full Ilse of Armor and I have only received 3 stars.

Answer (score 1):

You gradually earn more stars throughout the story of the game, and by the time you beat Leon and become the champion, you will have five. You earn one more by completing the story in the isle of armor by obtaining an Urshifu that can Gigantamax. And you earn one last one for completing the Galarian star tournament for the first time with whatever partner you chose. I highly recommend Hop for the first time. I know all of this information for a fact because I have all seven stars. You also earn one icon on your League card for each Pokédex you complete. It looks like a Rotom phone with a crown on it.

Comment: This is correct, but at which points do you get the first five stars? They're not obtained all at once by beating Leon; they are obtained at various points throughout the main story.

Answer (score 0):

I got the first five making a lot of kind of curry and doing the rally, of course beating Leon too.

Comment: Do you know how many stars were earned from making curry, doing the rally, and beating Leon separately?

Comment: During my second playthrough, I got all the main gain's stars without doing the rally or making curry once